# write where not in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to write this SQL using eloquent in laravel 5.6 application

```
select * from `lock_dates` where not (`start_at` >= '2018-11-25 23:59:59' or `end_at` <= '2018-11-21 00:00:00')
```

I don't know how to write **not**!

this is my eloquent code so far

```
LockDate::where('start_at' , '>=' , $end)
          ->orWhere('end_at' , '<=' , $start)
          ->get();
```

this is the SQL query that eloquent run behind the scenes which is the same SQL with I want except the **not**

```
0 => array:3 [▼
"query" => "select * from lock_dates where start_at >= ? or end_at <= ?"
"bindings" => array:2 [▼
  0 => "2018-11-25 23:59:59"
  1 => "2018-11-21 00:00:00"
]
"time" => 1.98
```

]

thanks in advance

Comment: question, shouldn't it be start_at >= 2018-11-21 and end_at<= 2018-11-25 ?

Comment: Eloquent essentially uses the builder, you can look at the source to determine exactly what you need: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php

Comment: @kapitan no. I want all records Except [records that end before 21 or records that start after 25 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need "not", your condition:

```
not (`start_at` >= '2018-11-25 23:59:59' or `end_at` <= '2018-11-21 00:00:00')
```

is equal to:

```
`start_at` <= '2018-11-25 23:59:59' AND `end_at` >= '2018-11-21 00:00:00'
```

So:

```
$lockDates = LockDate::where('start_at' , '<=' , $end)
    ->where('end_at' , '=>' , $start)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think the equals signs need to be removed, since the original query had them.

Comment: Corrected answer.

Comment: you are right. there is no need to not my condition in this case . but out of curiosity if I needed to not the conditions . how should I do that? it may help the others with the same problem too. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think kapitan is closest, but should be like this?

```
LockDate::whereDate('start_at' , '<' , $end)
          ->whereDate('end_at' , '>' , $start)
          ->get();
```

This is like checking your `not` request because the dates are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

To write `NOT` in Eloquent, use `!=` instead of `=` in your `WHERE` clause.

It will look like this:

```
`LockDate::where('start_at' , '!=' , $end)->get();`
```

Comment: This code dose not generate the sql i wrote .

The not implies on both condition

Comment: LockDate::whereDate('start_at' , '!=' , $end)
          ->whereDate('end_at' , '!=' , $start)
          ->get();

Answer (score 0):

there is actually a whereDate() for eloquent date filtering.

```
LockDate::whereDate('start_at' , '>=' , $end)
          ->whereDate('end_at' , '<=' , $start)
          ->get();
```

Comment: Right . Thanks . What about 'not' ?